# Can Python set these variables at once?

Tags: python

I have these initializations:

```
countrys = []
codes = []
index_countrys = {}
index_codes = {}
```

I want to declare them at once like this:

```
countrys,codes = []
index_countrys,index_codes = {}
```

Is that allowed in Python?

Comment: You want `countrys` and `codes` to be the same list? `countrys = codes = []` otherwise, `countrys,codes = [],[]`.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by saying 'set variables at once'. Are you talking about one line code for initializing all variables? Nevertheless, you can write like the following `countrys, codes, index_countrys, index_codes = [], [], {}, {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```python
countries, codes = [], []
index_countries, index_codes = {}, {}
```

or even :

```python
countries, codes, index_countries, index_codes = [], [], {}, {}
```

This is a good way to set multiple variables to distinct values using only a single line of code.

Searching  “*python set multiple variables site:stackoverflow.com*” will give you many other options and recommendations on which ones to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
countrys, code = [], []
index_countrys, index_codes = {}, {}
```

Comment: Answers are better if code is presented along with an explanation. It might help OP if you provided an explanation of how parallel assignment works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

On python you can declare chained vars with equals sign.
Just like that:

```py
countrys = codes = []
index_countrys = index_codes = {}
```

Comment: This does not create two separate unique lists or two separate dictionaries. Both variables will point to the same list or dictionary. It is not equivalent to the example given by the OP.

Comment: Fair enough! You're right! The [S22673 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63627141/14167472) is the correct one!